# How to select single or multiple checkbox buttons?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html

For each question, I want to compile an `if` statement where by checking through each question if the `.ReplyType` text input equals `Single`, then the user can only select a single checkbox button option, otherwise if the `.ReplyType` text input equals `Multiple`, then the user can select multiple checkbox button options.

My question is how to implement this if a single button or multiple buttons are selected depending on the `.ReplyType` text input? Is it better in PHP or JavaScript?

Below is relevant code:

```
<form action='results.php' method='post' id='exam'>

    <?php

//COMPILE OPTION BUTTONS

    function ExpandOptionType($option) { 
        $options = explode('-', $option);
        if(count($options) > 1) {
            $start = array_shift($options);
            $end = array_shift($options);
            do {
                $options[] = $start;
            }while(++$start <= $end);
         }
         else{
            $options = explode(' or ', $option);
         }

         foreach($options as $indivOption) {
             echo '<div class="ck-button"><label class="fixedLabelCheckbox"><input type="checkbox" name="options[]" id="option-' . $indivOption . '" value="' . $indivOption . '" /><span>' . $indivOption . '</span></label></div>';
         }


    }


    foreach ($arrQuestionId as $key=>$question) {

    ?>

    <div class="queWrap">

//DISPLAY QUESTION NUMBER FOR EACH QUESTION
    <p><?php echo htmlspecialchars($arrQuestionNo[$key]);?></p>

//DISPLAY OPTION CHECKBOX BUTTONS FOR EACH QUESTION
    <?php echo ExpandOptionType(htmlspecialchars($arrOptionType[$key])); ?>

//DISPLAY REPLY TYPE TEXT INPUT FOR EACH QUESTION
    <p>Reply Type: <input type='text' class='replyType' name='replytype' value='<?php echo htmlspecialchars($arrReplyType[$key]); ?>' /></p>



    </div>


    <?php

    }

    ?>
```

Comment: For single you would use PHP to output `<input type="radio" ... />` not a checkbox, and you wouldn't involve javascript

Comment: @popnoodles So you are saying in php if question is reply type is single, make it radio buttons else if multiple make it checkboxes?

Comment: @Mörre Yeah I just realised before you posted you comment. Wasn't thinking :)

Comment: Please take the time to learn about form elements.

Comment: @popnoodles I am getting undefined index for `$qandaReplyType` in the `foreach($options as $indivOption){` when writing this: `if($qandaReplyType == 'Single'){`. Can I ask what the variable should be called in the loop?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should do both, JavaScript and PHP implementation.

JavaScript is better for the user to get a response before submitting the form.

PHP is important, because JavaScript validation can be bypassed (just deactivate JavaScript) in this case your PHP should still validate that you get consistent data.

Anyway: Use radio-buttons for single-select and checkboxes for multi-select. Not that it's already implemented in every browser and meant to be used that way, most users have already learned this behavious and won't be surprised by your JavaScript (or PHP) validation.